# Razor View client side validation not working for fields with default values of First Name and Last Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**How can I do client side validation on the First Name and Last Name, preferably unobtrusive.**

I have 3 fields, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email Address`. There value is defaulted to their respective field names, as shown in the screenshot below. When I hit submit, the E-mail is shown as invalid because, of-course "Email Address" is a invalid email. But as you may have guessed, the "First Name" and "Last Name" pass perfectly fine because, "First Name" and "Last name" are not really considered to be invalid...

**Before submitting form:**

[image]

**After submitting form:**

[image]

**My View Model**

```
    public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-mail address is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(150)]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Please verify your e-mail address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**The Registration View**

```
<div class="content">
    <section>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Registration</legend>
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.FirstName, 
                        new {name="FirstName", 
                            onfocus="if (this.value=='FIRST NAME') this.value = ''",
                            onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'FIRST NAME'",
                            Value="FIRST NAME"})


                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.LastName, 
                        new {name="LastName", 
                            onfocus="if (this.value=='LAST NAME') this.value = ''",
                            onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'LAST NAME'",
                            Value="LAST NAME"})


                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.Email, 
                        new {name="EMail", 
                            onfocus="if (this.value=='EMAIL ADDRESS') this.value = ''",
                            onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'EMAIL ADDRESS'",
                            Value="EMAIL ADDRESS"})


                    <button class="glow" type="submit">Learn More</button>
                </div> 
                    <div class="validation-messages">
                        <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)</p>
                        <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)</p>
                        <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) </p>
                    </div> 
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
    </section>  
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate a `placeholder` text?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan I'm trying to validate the content that replaces the placeholder text. The problem arises when the user doesn't enter anything at all... Its not a blank `textbox`, it has the place holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to set their default values to their property names. Not sure why are you doing that. In my opinion you need to set the placeholder attribute value to be their property names:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.FirstName, new { placeholder = "First Name"} )
```

This will work for you in any HTML 5 capable browser so if you need it to work on IE7 then forget it.

If you want to stick with your initial setup then you need to set a regular expression validator to invalidate the entry if the value is "First Name". You can go to:

http://www.regexr.com/

and try to generate the proper regular expression.

Comment: Great answer +1, I was not even aware the `placeholder` attribute existed, it made me smile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you're actually setting the value of the textbox to what you'd like as a placehold. You can use the placeholder tag[1]

Add a `new {placeholder = "..."}` to the end of your TextBoxFor declarations instead of using `onfocus` and `onblur` and that should do the trick.

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder